# Default value in data table design

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm designing a data table in Access. I have two columns whose values are something like:

col1: CU001-

col2: 03

and i want to join these two string to form another column's default value like: CU001-03
How can i do this?

And one more question is whether using a string as main key tends to be much slower than a numeric?

Comment: It's bad design to store duplicate data. Anything that can be derived from existing columns can be constructed as needed for display purposes. The only exception I can think of is if somehow the combined version needs to be searched, but in this case, you clearly have two independent pieces of data that can be parsed separately, and thus, that's not an issue at all. All that said, Access 2010 adds table-level data macros that can be used like triggers so that you could populate this field in the Insert event. I WOULD RECOMMEND AGAINST IT, but it's possible with A2010.

Comment: Split your questions. It makes them easier to answer and use as a reference by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m fairly sure (but open to correction) that you cant have this kind of thing in access using the default value however you can get the same effect by doing something like this.

If you have an unbound form then you can set the value of your 3rd column before you save it like this presto code

```
With rst
    !YourCol1=”foo”
    !YourCol2=”bar”
    !YourCol3= !YourCol1 & !YourCol2
    .Update
End with
```

Search on “unbound forms” on google to see full examples of unbound forms, also if you are only using JET to store your data then use DAO over ADO as it will be faster

EDIT

I have not read any books specifically on access but I can strongly recommend a few access websites that have helped me. Here they are in no particular order

http://www.mvps.org/access/
http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/
http://www.lebans.com/
http://allenbrowne.com/tips.html

There are many more out there but they are a good place to start

Comment: OK that is to say i cant do it in the design window but i can use VBA code while i set up those forms... i see

Comment: @darkjh Yep spot on you will have to do some coding. This MIGHT have changed in access 2010 as I know it has "Triggers" but I dont have a copy of that so cant say for sure

Comment: thanks.. im doing my internship, my job is to make a ACCESS based tools control application. But i dont know much about ACCESS, any book recommended?

Comment: @Darkjh I have added some links to my post to help you out